# Plot graphs in R software

Tags: r

In using R software I face the error term which is:

```
 dmodel1=list()
 for(i in 1:12){
 sun.st = i     
 data1 = fdata(file1, nd = nd, sun.st)
 d1= ffit(data1,order=2)
 dmodel1[[i]]=d1
 fplot(d1, plot.year,label=colnames(data1)[2],ylab=1)
 cat(colnames(data1)[2], "\n")
 }
```

the error is:

```
 Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
 2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : - not meaningful for factors
 3: In Ops.factor(x[, 2], dataff1f) : - not meaningful for factors
 4: In max(dataFF2[, 3], na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

So, would you please help me to overcome this?

Thanks 
Bah

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce the error if you use some random values in your variables? Without the data is difficult to assess whether the data is somehow "corrupted" (or at least inadequate for what you want to do).